# What's level-scaled in Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

What's level-scaled in the game?

I've got LV6 Kraggon Pebbles in Serenity's Waste and entered it as a LV5 Doppelganger.

The loot inside the chest of the quest Oz Kit location was, on two different occasions, LV5 Grenade Mods (Green, White, White), and 3 LV5 White Oz Kits.

Also, enemies and rocks seem to be dropping moonstones at an elevated rate. I found a 4 Moonstone chunk inside a rock, and a Kraggon Pebble dropped one too.

Comment: Usually in your first run there is a soft cap to which lvl enemies can be scaled, but this can be softened up by defeating some key opponents even in another map. However if there is something like a "True Vault Hunter mode" in BLTPS (which i don't know) usually enemies scale up there with you

Comment: @procra - Yeah, all BL games have NG+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the level for Elpis is set at whatever you enter Serenity's Waste as, and everything gets level-ups after killing Red Belly, or completing the related mission.

But I'm not sure if that causes new level-scaling or just a level increase to 10.

Stanton's Liver seems to level-scale on entry... Or something. The level seems to be indicated by the first Cryo Vine in the area. I can tell it's based on something after arriving on Elpis, but not sure what. It doesn't seem like (Deadlift Kill Level? Chapter 3 Trigger Level? Concordia or Triton Flats entry level?) -2...

Might just me being wrong on my levels on entering Elpis. It might just be [that] + 5. And level-scaling seems to be by ranges. LV6 Wilheim entering Serenity's Waste still seems to be LV5 stuff. LV5 Loot, and Phonic, etc.