# Is it possible to trigger level scaling at the very beginning of the game, through co-op techniques?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I know with co-op, a lower-level character can fight higher-level enemies than they usually would have access to, so-long as the host is the higher level.

I don't have access to my copy right now so I can't test this myself, but is it possible to host for someone that's never even started the first mission, bring them up to a higher level, like 6, and that way the partner's Welcome to Helios will have Level 6 enemies, loot, and maybe unlocked vendors?

[Like how](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/377996/whats-level-scaled-in-borderlands-the-pre-sequel) grinding to levels like 5 or 8 in the Station, means that Serenity's Waste is a higher level compared to regular progression, but this question is asking about achieving the effect for the tutorial section of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use co-op to make the Helios Station tutorial harder, but that also makes the rest of the beginning, at least, easier.

Note that Vendors outside of the DLC areas seem to adjust themselves to the player's level, instead of the location's, so it is possible to get Class and Grenade Mods in the tutorial. Along with getting more than pistols from the tutorial chests, if the area's level is 3. Untested for 2.

But if you level scale the tutorial, it seems that Serenity's Waste *isn't* level scaled and will be locked at 4, even if you enter it as a LV10.

If you want to get the Marooned quest, and the locations of Serenity's Waste (and Regolith Range?) to its level cap, which appears to be 5, which gives Deadlift a level of 7, it appears that you'll have to sacrifice the level scaling of the tutorial.

Given that Marooned's seemingly minimum level is 3, the pattern seems to be that the level cap is two levels higher than the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Enemies and loot are tied to the mission level, and since [Welcome to Helios](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Welcome_to_Helios) is a level 1 mission you always find low level enemies and you receive a fixed reward ($22, 107 XP and a lousy Shield).

Missions only scale in *Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode*, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Oh. hmm. I meant "Welcome To Helios" in a less Quest like manner, as in the party's "Welcome" to Helios, with guns. And Fire.
...
Gonna make my question more clear...