# In Co-op as a Baroness, wielding a Capital Sniper Rifle (Incendiary), mysteriously got a Deadlift Quick Kill through shields

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

In Co-op as a Baroness, wielding a 92 damage Capital Sniper Rifle (Incendiary), and 600+ on a crit. Mysteriously got a Deadlift Quick Kill through shields.

While grinding up / carrying [my Gladiator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/396780/108916), I decided to take on Deadlift solo, because I got everyone to his Bastion of Bounce for the location EXP anyway.

So, as my LV 9 Baroness wielding a Blue-rarity Incendiary Capital Sniper Rifle, where I tried and failed a few times, suddenly mysteriously, I land a hit and Deadlift dies while still at a lot of shields. I think.

Anyone know how that happened? I wouldn't think that him being affected by Cold As Ice would matter?

Unless he can actually freeze and be shattered? But that's just a guess I just made. I've never seen a boss be frozen.

On fighting him again, his Health Bar seems extremely weak compared to his shields, actually. Such that it seems like it only took one hit to bring him down? So it might be just that? But I don't know how much HP he has vs. his shields.

What's the odds that I actually had a glitch vs. I just wasn't paying attention and accidentally drained all his shields then took him down with a headshot?

Or in another manner, "What's the Shield amount and HP of a LV6 Deadlift?"

Comment: It indeed sounds like a glitch. His shield is far more powerful than his health. Given your Capital Sniper rifle was incendiary, i doublt a single crit shot will be enough to one shot him. Maybe the elemental type got mistook as shock, which receives a damage bonus against shields, leaving more damage capaity deployed to his health. Then you would have been a lucky icycle.